# text box loses focus on iphone

Tags: asp.net, iphone, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a mobile webpage that works fine in browser in PC and in Iphone safari browser.
This page has a search box with auto-suggest feature.

My client has a iphone native app, and he pulls this page into his native app.
With in the app, when user start typing in the search box, after the first letter, the lookup results popup, search box loses focus and the keypad goes away.

When you click in the text box and continue typing, every thing is fine.

Any ideas on whats going on or how to even debug this?